# how to find the characters between 2 strings in excel

Tags: string, excel, format

I have an xml file imported into excel with the tags. How do i retrieve the value of the string between 2 strings.

Eg. "<"product_offer_group_id">"686819743"<"/product_offer_group_id">"

How do i retrieve 686819743 from this. To note the string length is varying and ranges from 1 to 20 digits.

Answer (score 0):

you need to procced in excel? Not sure about possibility of usage of regular expressions(which are a pretty good solution for that case) in Excel standard functions, but with VBA You can for sure.

look here:
http://lispy.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/using-regex-functions-in-excel/

Alternativelly you can also try to play with standard Excel Text functions, like find, left, right etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution without using VB script and only Excel functions, assuming your value is in cell A1, the following use of `MID`, `FIND`, and `CHAR` functions would work:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(34)&">"&CHAR(34),A1,1)+3,FIND(CHAR(34)&"<"&CHAR(34),A1,FIND(CHAR(34)&">"&CHAR(34),A1,1)+1)-FIND(CHAR(34)&">"&CHAR(34),A1,1)-3)
```

The above searches for the first occurrence of the tag ">", and takes whatever is between that tag and the next occurring "<" tag.

The magic number 3 in the function is the length of these two searched tags and used to cut down on calling an additional `LEN(CHAR(34)&">"&CHAR(34))` function.